# WordPress isn't sending welcome email with the password reset

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, email, user-registration

So I have been debugging the code:

```
$message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";

$message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password info'), $blogname), $message);
```

If I remove the `$message` variable from `wp_mail()` and replace with with "hello" it sends fine, but if I use the message variable, I get no errors, it claims to have sent, but never actually gets sent.

What causes this, and how can I fix the `$message` variable?

Comment: Unfortunately with WordPress emails, you can't assume that because WordPress claims to have sent an email, that it was both sent and received. There are many places it can go wrong. Your host could be blocking certain outbound, your email mailbox provider could be blocking certain inbound. It could be received but sent to spam. We wrote a post on how to eliminate the first problem to ensure email sending doesn't rely on your web host. Do this for all sites you manage.  https://www.icontrolwp.com/blog/trouble-free-email-solution-wordpress-mandrillapp/

Comment: I've tried with different SMTP plugins, and none work, no emails are being sent. I've also done a fresh install.

Comment: You mentioned that if you remove the $message variable and replace with a standard string the message is sent. This tells me there's some issue with the value of the message variable. Have you tried commenting every line bar one to narrow down what is specifically causing the issue? E.g comment everything except line 1, does it send? No. Ok comment everything except line 2, does it send? Yes. The problem then is with line 1 and the problem is now more specific and could lead to the solution.

Comment: It seems to be breaking on the last 2 url lines the netowork_site_url and the wp_login_url

Comment: Just a comment in reply to your reply about SMTP plugins. I'm talking about NOT using SMTP plugins. Using SMTP is where many things go wrong on a lot of hosting. Best of luck.